# RabbitMQ + WebSocket Chat Architecture

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, chat, message-queue

I'm developing a chat service using RabbitMQ and WebSockets. This is my architecture:

[image]

Some observations:

- I think the main drawback of this architecture is each WebSocket client receives a copy of the message delivered by Client A. If client B is not connected to this WebSocket, the message is just ignored.
- Load Balancer B has sticky session enabled, so clients will always reconnect to the same WebSocket service.
- The number of instances of chat API is not always the same as WebSocket services.
- Load Balancer ware implemented using Nginx
- Chat API and WebSocket service both are implemented using Nodejs
- Clients are Android, iOS, or Web apps.

Do you guys have any tips on how to improve this?

Comment: Did you find any answer?
I am also thinking to build a chat application with Websocket and one of the JMS providers but I don't know if that's a good idea or good practice. How did it go?